# MySQL in Ubuntu Linux - I cannot connect to the server

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I am new in MySQL. I installed Workbench and server. When i try to connect to the database server i receive a message: Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' to the MySQL server. Ann AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recepient; type .

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

AppArmor is a Linux kernel security module that allows the system administrator to restrict programs' capabilities with per-program profiles. Have you tried to disable it and see if the connection works?
Check here on how to do that: [help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor#Disable_AppArmor_framework](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor#Disable_AppArmor_framework)

Another idea you can check with `ss -tnl` if you can see `localhost:3306` on listening mode, if `ss` is not available use `netstat -tnl`

```
$ man ss
ss - another utility to investigate sockets
-t, --tcp
    Display TCP sockets.

-n, --numeric
    Do not try to resolve service names. Show exact bandwidth values, instead of human-readable.

l, --listening
    Display only listening sockets (these are omitted by default).


# Usually something like that means you have the service listening on 
# localhost port 3306 in that case the port you configured your mysql to be running
State   Recv-Q   Send-Q     Local Address:Port      Peer Address:Port  Process  
LISTEN  0        4096           127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*
```